# How to make the middle widget of the scrollable-row to show in the left when page initiated?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have some challenging problem -*at least for me*- here.

So, I have a list of `Container` here that placed inside a `Row`. And then, the `Row` wrapped using `SingleChildScrollView`, and have `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,`, so the `Row` could be scrolled horizontally.

Here`s the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Scrollable WIdgets"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Container #1 ============================
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 250.0,
                width: 250.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('A'),
                ),
              ),
              
              // Container #2 ============================
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: 250.0,
                width: 250.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('B'),
                ),
              ),
              
              // Container #3 ============================
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                color: Colors.green,
                height: 250.0,
                width: 250.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('C'),
                ),
              ),
              
              // Container #4 ============================
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                color: Colors.yellow,
                height: 250.0,
                width: 250.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('D'),
                ),
              ),
              
              // Container #5 ============================
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                color: Colors.pink,
                height: 250.0,
                width: 250.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('E'),
                ),
              ),
              
              
            ]
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When the screen is built, Container A (or Container #1) will be shown in the most left of the screen:
[image: Initial]

**My question is**, *how to make the Container C (or container #3) show up in the most left of the screen on the screen's first build? but the horizontal scroll function still running as usual.* (see the image below for more understanding)

[image: The goal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the width of your children, you can just explicitly set the `controller` property of the `SingleChildScrollView` with a `ScrollController` and define the `initialScrollOffset`. I think the `ScrollController` would need to be created in a stateful widget and used as a variable, so something like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 560.0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Scrollable WIdgets"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: controller,
          (...)
```

The value of initialScrollOffset is defined by the width of the row children plus their margins, so `2*250 + 4*15 = 560`

Comment: Nice soutions! Thank you so much.